# Gtk - exiting a multi-window program

Tags: python, gtk, glade

I'm having some issues while trying to exit a multi window program, 2 to be exact. 
There is a connect window and a main window. If the user clicks on the native X button of the connect window it closes, the program ends and all is well.

But if the user do connect and the main window opens, if then the user clicks on the main window's X button, the window will close but the process won't terminate.

I've tried different approaches and none seemed to work, so this is the current state of the code:

The connect window (the `self.window.connect('delete-event', gtk.main_quit)` line is commented because the delete-event is bounded to the quit method in my .glade file):

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gio


class ConnectWinHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, window, builder, gtk):
        self.window = window
        self.builder = builder
        self.gtk = gtk
        # self.window.connect('delete-event', self.gtk.main_quit)

    def connect_button_clicked(self, widget):
        ip, port = self.ip_port_entry.get_text().split(':')
        try:
            # some irrelevant connection logic
        except IOError as ex:
            # irrelevant error handling
        else:
            main_window = MainWin(self.window, self.gtk)
            self.window.close()
            main_window.show_all()

    def quit(self, widget, data=None):
        self.gtk.main_quit()


class ConnectWin(object):
    def __init__(self, gtk):
        self.gtk = gtk
        self.builder = self.gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file(r'some_path_to_glade_file')
        self.window = self.builder.get_object('main')
        self.builder.connect_signals(ConnectWinHandler(self.window, self.builder, self.gtk))

    def show_all(self):
        self.window.show_all()
        self.gtk.main()
```

The main window (again, `self.window.connect('delete-event', self.gtk.main_quit)` is commented because the delete-event is bounded to the quit method in my .glade file):

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gio, GObject

class MainWinHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, connect_win, window, builder, gtk):
        self.connect_win = connect_win
        self.window = window
        self.builder = builder
        self.gtk = gtk
        # self.window.connect('delete-event', self.gtk.main_quit)

    def quit(self, widget, data=None):
        self.gtk.main_quit()


class MainWin(object):
    def __init__(self, connect_win, gtk, krpc_handler):
        self.gtk = gtk
        self.builder = self.gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file(r'path_to_glade_file')
        self.window = self.builder.get_object('main')
        self.builder.connect_signals(MainWinHandler(connect_win, self.window, self.builder, self.gtk, krpc_handler))

    def show_all(self):
        self.window.show_all()
        self.gtk.main()
```

I don't think it matters, but each window is in it's own .py file, and the program is started from a third file:

```
from gui.connect_win import ConnectWin
from gi.repository import Gtk

connect_win = ConnectWin(Gtk)
connect_win.show_all()
```

Comment: Just use GtkApplication which handles multiple GtkApplicationWindows for you.